# How to use async all the way up to the top

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have generic repository which has async methods `FindAsync`:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private dynamic _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    protected DbContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext();
            }

            return _context;
        }
    }

    protected DbSet<TEntity> DBSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbSet == null)
            {
                _dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }

            return _dbSet;
        }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderExpression = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> qry = DBSet;

        if (predicate != null)
        {
            qry = qry.Where(predicate);
        }

        if (orderExpression != null)
        {
            return orderExpression(qry);
        }

        return qry;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderExpression = null) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = Context.Set<T>();
        IQueryable<T> qry = dbSet;

        if (predicate != null)
        {
            qry = qry.Where(predicate);
        }

        if (orderExpression != null)
        {
            return orderExpression(qry);
        }

        return qry;
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderExpression = null)
    {
        return await GetQuery(predicate, orderExpression).ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderExpression = null) where T : class
    {
        return await GetQuery<T>(predicate, orderExpression).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And then I created a `CustomerRepository` which calls `FindAsync` from generic repo:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _repo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Hookup dependencies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repo"></param>
    public CustomerRepository(IRepository<Customer> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;

        //Disable entity proxy creation and  lazy loading.
        _repo.LazyLoadingEnabled(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets customer by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<Customer> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return await _repo.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id).Result.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

The the problem that I have is that when I call `await _repo.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id).Result.SingleOrDefaultAsync();`

It says

> IEnumerable Customer does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefaultAsync.

Anyone knows what I missed?

Comment: That is one of your problems. the other is that you are mixing blocking call `.Result` with `async/await` calls.

Comment: FindAsync returns IEnumerable<T> from the generic repository.
Now in my customer repository, I want method GetByIdAsync calls FindAsync and should only return single item that matches the predicate that's why I am using .Result

Comment: Check your using statements, are you missing a reference to System.Data.Entity?

Comment: @AndrewReyes That's not a reason to use `Result`.  You should `await` the `Task` to write code that uses the result instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding with how [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) is being used.

Use the `await` operator on an `async` method returning a `Task` type to suspend execution of the method until the awaited task completes.

Then the return value will be assigned to the variable.

```
public async Task<Customer> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    // Call the async method to get the task returning the customers
    Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> customersTask = _repo.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id);

    // Wait for the customers to be fetched
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers = await customersTask;

    // Get the customer
    return customers.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This is analogous to:

```
public async Task<Customer> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    var customers = await _repo.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id);
    return customers.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @AndrewReyes As shown in the first example, you will have a plain `IEnumerable<Customer>`, so there are no async methods needed.

Answer (score 3):

That is one of your problems. the other is that you are mixing blocking call `.Result` with `async/await` calls.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets customer by id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<Customer> GetByIdAsync(Guid id) {
    var records = await _repo.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id);
    return records.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Also make sure you have the proper reference [QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync Method (IQueryable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220228(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add
     using System.Data.Entity
 to the using statements on the top of CustomerRepository.cs

Change The returntype of FindAsync to return IQueryable

See [QueryableExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync(v=vs.113).aspx) vor further guidance

Also, don't mix blocking calls (.Result) with async/await like The later comments suggest.

Comment: It wont work, unless FindAsync method returns IQueryable, but in my case  it returns IEnumerable

Comment: Oh yeah, i accidently referred to The wrong method signature. See edit in a sec.